# Difference between POST data escaping and HTML escaping?

Tags: html

What is the difference between data escaped for POST vars and data escaped for text in HTML paras?

I know that HTML does not support certain chars in strings such as & which must become `&amp;` and so on.

Does POST data (for forms) require "URL escaping"? as in, "Hello World" becomes "Hello%20World"??

Comment: In what context is this an issue?  The client browser deals with constructing POST requests on the user's behalf.  So are you talking about generating HTTP POST requests manually?

Comment: I think that the question is a bit generic, or incomplete. First I'd say that it depends on what are you going to do with $_POST because it may become HTML again. If you clarify the circumstances, is easier to give a good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend of the "content-type" in your http-header.

For example, if your content-type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" you MUST url encoded your POST like a GET string.
If your content-type is "multipart/form-data", you DON'T url encoded your POST data.

Answer (score 1):

Posted data has a content type. Each content type has its own format. Some involve escaping, some do not. You need to choose a content type and then format appropriately.

application/x-www-form-urlencoded is one common example.

[The HTML Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) will tell you its rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can use htmlentities() if you need to preserve the code sent in the $_POST[] string, but for being shown only as plain text. If you don't need or want to show the code tags, then you can use strip_tags() which will give you a string containing only regular text. And mysqli_real_escape_string() is used when you are going to use the submitted data in a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

HTML escaping is one task possible when you want to escape POST data.

POST data escaping usually means you want to espace data entered by the user to avoid XSS and SQL injection. So you basically need to escape quotes and HTML tags.
For example, `<strong>Take 'em all</strong>` will become `&lt;strong&gt;Take \'em all &lt;/strong&gt;`

This applies on GET data also, or everything the user can do, of course.

See also: [When do you escape your data?](http://n0tw0rthy.wordpress.com/2011/10/07/when-do-you-escape-your-data/)

Comment: But that has nothing to do with POST.  That's simply what you need to do to *any* string data that you're going to substitute into an SQL query or some output HTML.